# Maintaining aspect ratio of a div contained by the browsers height with no javascript

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I need a div with the aspect ratio of 320x576 aligned horizontally central in the browser with the height equal to the browser ie 100vh so that when the browser height changes the width of the div changes accordingly. I'd rather not use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to specify the following CSS for the div `margin: auto; height: 100vh; width: 55.55vh;` ?

55.55vh / 100vh keeps the aspect ratio 320/576

I think it should work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to follow the aspect ratio that depends on the 100vh. Try to use **calc** of css and set it on the width of your div.

```
div {
   height: 100vh;
   width: calc(100vh * (320 / 576));
}
```

with that, whenever what window height you get, the width will follow depends on the aspect ratio of 320x576 without using javascript :)